# Does a private visit visa to Azerbaijan require an invitation from the foreign ministry?

Tags: visas, azerbaijan

I am from Yemen. I have been living in Azerbaijan for the past 5 years, and I am facing an issue where I don't know what to do and from where to get accurate information. The situation is as follows:

My sister is coming here to study and she has an invitation from the foreign ministry. She is divorced and she has a 4-year-old daughter, whom she wants to bring with her. We asked the foreign ministry and migration in ASAN what documents were needed, and how we should proceed with her daughter's visa. They said there is no direct way she can come here unless her mom comes here first and then invites her, or she gets an invitation from an Azerbaijani person. Then she can get 90 days for private visit. Then she applies under her mom when applying for a temporary residency card here.

The situation got a little bit complicated when my mom, aunty and my brother wanted to come with my sister for a short visit to Azerbaijan too. So we asked again what we should do and how we should apply, and the reply was the same thing: if they want to stay more than 30 days, they should apply for a private visit, which gives them up to 90 days.

We prepared all the documents needed (invitations from Azerbaijani, commitment letter, bank statements, supporting documents + all other docs needed).

They traveled to Cairo from Yemen and went to the Azerbaijan Embassy. The guy working there told them that they need an invitation from the foreign ministry. So we went to the foreign ministry and asked what we needed to get this paper. They said there is no such paper for a private visit. They only give it for people who are coming to work, study or on an official visit. I have looked at [Azerbaijan migration law](https://migration.gov.az/content/pdf/60ed89e2411a5_M%C9%99c%C9%99ll%C9%99%20%C4%B0ngilis.pdf) and pages for visa requirements of embassies not only in Cairo but in many other capitals in the world and I can't find anything.

They went again today to the embassy to tell them that the foreign ministry said all papers required to get a visa were already there, and that they don't give an invitation for private visits. But the guy again said we must get a paper from the foreign ministry.

I am now in a situation where we are bouncing between two parties, where each is saying the opposite thing. I am not sure how I can move forward with this. Would you have any help, suggestions or information that can help me?

Answer (score 1):

The English pdf you are referring (which is translated in the Migration Service's website) is *almost* up-to-date with the [official code](https://e-qanun.az/framework/46959) in Azerbaijani.

Articles 30 and 36 relate to you.

From the English version,

> 36.1.6. An application of a party inviting the foreigner or stateless person to the Republic of Azerbaijan, sample of which was approved by
> the relevant executive authority (this documents shall not be required
> to apply for transit and tourist visas);

But the official Azerbaijani version mentions that it is NOT required also for official and private visits. So you don't need this.

> *...(tranzit, turizm, rəsmi və şəxsi səfər vizaları üçün bu sənəd tələb olunmur);*

I believe what they want from you is:

> 36.1.1. An application form specimen of which was approved by the relevant executive authority;

You can fill this application at the website of the Ministry of Foreign Affairs https://visaapplication.mfa.gov.az/. In your case you shall select Cairo, Egypt as your location.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, We filled the application form from the exact same site before we went to embassy to submit. they are asking for Invitation from foreign ministry :( . which looks like there is no such thing for privet visit

Comment: There's no such thing for any kind of visa. Why would MFA of Azerbaijan invite anyone? People or legal entities invite other people, not the MFA. In the second paragraph, you say "My sister... has an invitation from the foreign ministry". What does it mean, she has an invitation from the foreign ministry?

MFA site [mentions](https://mfa.gov.az/en/category/visa/documents-required-for-the-invitation-of-foreigner-or-stateless-person-to-the-republic-of-azerbaijan) an application form that needs to be submitted TO the MFA when inviting side is a legal entity but it doesn't apply to you.

Comment: For students we apply in https://portal.edu.az/ , then university send to MFA as far as i know and once they approve they give paper to which we go to embassy and apply with